# Comparing text values to a constant in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to compare values from 3 textbox to a constant to check if the value from individual textbox is greater than a constant. I have written the below code but it is giving below error that cannot compare int. How to check that?

```
private void txtResult_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
    if (aSub1 && aSub2 && aSub3) > 40
    {

    }
}
```

`aSub1`, `aSub2` & `aSub3` are textbox variables.

Comment: What type of comparison you need .. it's `textlength`??

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to achieve? Which information is stored in the text boxes? What is 40 represents?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert first textbox values to `int` type

```
private void txtResult_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int iSub1, iSub2,iSub3;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(aSub1.Text, out iSub1)
           || !Int32.TryParse(aSub2.Text, out iSub2)
           || !Int32.TryParse(aSub3.Text, out iSub3))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid integer");
            return;
        }
        if (iSub1>40 && iSub2>40 && iSub3>40)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to get the Text property of the `TextBox : aSub1.Text`, `aSub2.Text`. With the given code, you are referring to the object itself.
- Second you need to check if the string value can be cast into int (since 40 seems int, otherwise relevant type)
- Third you need to compare each value individually and **"AND**" the results of comparisons